# How to store the int of specific bits(24bits, 16bits, etc) in Python?

Tags: python

When I do the compress the data with compact code, I don't know how to deal with the integer, I need to store an integer into 1bytes, 2bytes, 3bytes, etc, memory, How can I do this in Python.

Or, how to change the tuple (1, 0, 1, ..., 1) (24bits) into exact 3bytes storage

Answer (score 1):

The [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) module in the standard library packs data into bytes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pack in arbitrary numbers of bytes then it might be better to use a `bytearray` than rely on the `struct` module, for example:

```
>>> a = bytearray(3)  # create 3 byte array
>>> a[0] = 0x3e
>>> a[1] = 0xff
>>> a[2] = 0x00
```

Note that the memory overhead of any Python object is going to be considerably more than a few bytes, so if you are really worried about memory use then you should store all your data together in as few objects as possible.

Depending on your exact needs a third party module such as [bitstring](http://python-bitstring.googlecode.com) could be helpful (full disclosure: I wrote it).

```
>>> b = bitstring.BitArray((1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1))
>>> b.bytes
'\xb9\xd7'
>>> b.uint
47575
```